# find self index for nested Python object

Tags: python, list, recursion, tree, nested

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = []
    def AddNode(self):
        self.children.append(Node(self))
    def getIndex(self):
        return self.parent.children.index(self)

a = Node()
b = a.AddNode()
print b.getIndex()
```

In a tree of objects like the above, what's the best way for a child to find out its index within the parent's children? I'm using `self.parent.children.index(self)`, but that seems contorted. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One nit: this doesn't quite work, because **AddNode** doesn't return anything.
Other than that what you've done is fine.  So long as you're doing on-demand (lazy) retrieval of the index, this is a direct way to do it.  If you want something more direct, I suggest that you store the index when the child is linked in **AddNode**.

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = []
        self.child_index = None

    def AddNode(self):
        new_child = Node(self)
        self.children.append(new_child)
        new_child.child_index = self.children.index(new_child)
        return new_child

    def getIndex(self):
        return self.child_index

a = Node()
b = a.AddNode()
c = a.AddNode()
d = a.AddNode()

print d.getIndex()
print c.getIndex()
print b.getIndex()
```

Output (*booooorrriiinnngg*):

```
2
1
0
```

Comment: Just the confirmation I needed, thanks. And yes, thanks for the reminder to return something in AddNode(). As you may have guessed, my real code does that, but I forgot to add it in the example. Cheers!

Comment: Glad to be of help.  Remember to "accept" an answer when you hit a cadence point: it lets StackOverflow properly retire the question.